# Speaking about tuples

Tags: word-usage

I wrote the following text:

> A restaurant has a fixed number of chairs. If they **set/arrange** them around tables **with 7 capacity** (put them in **groups of 7**), no chair **is extra**. If they set them around tables with 4 capacity, 2 chair is extra. If they set them around tables with 3 capacity, 1 chair is extra. How many numbers smaller than 1000 are there for the number of chairs of the restaurant?

First, I would like to know is **set...around** correct and common for chairs around a table? could I use **arrange**?

Then I don't know the related words for groups with a certain capacity, and also the words for what remains after arranging objects in groups.

Could you rewrite the text above containing idiomatic words for such a scenario?

Comment: **set** or **arrange**. Both OK.   But "7 capacity" should be "a capacity of seven" or "tables that seat seven".  Also note verb-subject number agreement.  "two chairs **are** extra" or "there are two chairs **left over**".

Comment: Nobody's said it so far, but I'd strongly advise "no chairs are left over" rather than "no chair is left over".

Answer (score 1):

Given the nature of what I *think* is your goal here (i.e. writing a mathematics puzzle for students), I would punctuate and employ repetition, so your students will see the pattern explictly.

Note that I am avoiding the explicit term "divide", so as not to explicitly instruct the students to perform mathematical division, and I am avoiding the more natural "remains", because of the connotation of "remainder" with "division".

To that end I would use "arrange" and "left over".  Depending on your audience it may be suitable to relax the restriction of "remains".

Consider:

> A restaurant has a fixed number of chairs.
>
> - If they arrange them in tables of seven, no chair is left over.
> - If they arrange them in tables of four, two chairs are left over.
> - If they arrange them in tables of three, one chair remains.
>
> The restaurant has less than 1000 chairs.
>
> ...(question discussed below)

Your final queston, "How many numbers smaller than 1000 are there for the number of chairs *in* the restaurant?" is tricky (although note I have change *of* to *in* for readability).

**If** the answer you are looking for is the number of solutions that meet the problem statements, then it is fine, albeit tricky, and some more-literal thinkers might feel cheated by such a question – perhaps that is the intent.

**If**, however, you want them to list the various possible numbers of chairs, you may need to be less ambiguous.  If you are happy to be specific, I'd suggest an instructional footnote:

> How many chairs are in the restaurant?
>   *(There are X possible solutions; please list them all)*

(You would substitute X for the right number of solutions.)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments I would write it as

> A restaurant has a fixed number of chairs. If they are set around tables with a capacity of 7 (divide them into groups of 7), no chair is left over. If they are set around tables with a capacity of 4, there are two chairs left over. If they are set around tables with a capacity of 3, one chair is left over. How many numbers smaller than 1000 are there for the capacity of the restaurant?

Comment: I am going to guess that express use of the term *divide* is intentionally avoided here, because it looks like the OP is setting a maths question, and wants the reader to *realise* that they have to do the mathematical division.